# $Gx$ is distributed uniformly in the set $\Bbb Z_2 ^n$.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, solution-verification, coding-theory

I read the probabilistic proof of the Gilbert Varshamov bound in Coding Theory, and I came across the following argument, which I would like to discuss:

Suppose that $G$ is a random matrix in $M_
{n×k} (\Bbb Z_2)
$. We fix a non zero element $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in \Bbb Z_2^k$.

Then, the element $Gx$ is distributed **uniformly** in the set $\Bbb Z_2 ^n$.

My intuition says that as all the elements $a_{ij}$ of $G=(a_{ij}) \in M_{n×k} (\Bbb Z_2)$ are picked at random, any element has the form $y=Gx=(a_{11} x_1+\dotsb +a_{ 1k} x_k,\dots, a_{n1}x_1+\dotsb +a_{nk} x_k)$ is just a random element of $\Bbb Z_2^n$ and thus has equal probability of occurrence $1/2^n$.

Update: The proof uses that a random generator matrix $G$ of size
${\displaystyle k×n}$ contains
${\displaystyle kn}$ elements which are chosen independently and uniformly over the field
$\mathbb {Z} _{2}$.

Is that correct? How could we show this more formally?

Comment: You could observe that the distribution of $G$ is the same as that of $GA$, for any invertible $k\times k$ matrix $A$.

Comment: Should the hypothesis mention that $G$ is uniformly distributed in $M_{k\times n} (\Bbb Z_2)$?

Comment: I'd assume the author meant "random matrix" to mean "random matrix with uniform distribution".

Comment: Thanks a lot for the Comments. I think your argument is implied by the Update of my question. Do you agree?

Answer (score 1):

Since $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is nonzero we can assume that at least one component, say $x_1$, is equal to $1.$

Clearly $x_1 U$ is equidistributed in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ if the random variable $U$ is equidistributed. Think of this $U$ as any random entry $a_{i,j}$ of the matrix.

Also clearly $x_1 U+c$ for *any* $c\in \mathbb{Z}_2$ is equidistributed. This is regardless of whether $c$ is deterministic or random with any distribution over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ since $x_1 U=U$ just flips the quantity $c$ between $0$ and $1$.

Finally any entry of $G x$ is of the form $x_1 U+c=U+c.$

Answer (score 0):

Please feel free to judge my justification:

Let $G\in M_{k\times n}$ be a uniformly random full-rank $k \times n$ matrix. For all $m\in \Bbb F_q^k\setminus \{0\}$ the random variable $mG$ is uniformly distributed in $\Bbb F_q^n\setminus \{0\}$.

Let $y,y'\in \Bbb F_q^n\setminus \{0\}$. We show that $\Pr(mG=y)=\Pr(mG=y')$. Indeed, there exists an invertible matrix $M\in GL_k(\Bbb F_q)$ such that $y=My'$. Then, $$\Pr(mG=y)=\Pr(mGM=yM)=\Pr(mGM=y').$$ Moreover, since the map $A\overset{f}{\longmapsto} AM$ is a bijection from the set of full rank $k\times n$ matrices onto itself. So, $GM$ is a uniformly random full rank $k\times n$ matrix. Therefore,  the probability that $mGM$ is equal to $y'$ is the same with the probability that $mG$ is equal to $y'$. Hence, $$\Pr(mGM=y')=\Pr(mG=y'),$$ so using the first lines $\Pr(mG=y')=\Pr(mGM=y')=\Pr(mG=y)$, as wanted.

Comment: The argument goes through even without assuming a full rank matrix, as in my answer, so this argument is a bit too powerful for the general case